# No viable overloaded "=" in objective c opencv

Tags: objective-c, opencv

I am trying to find bounding box on contours in image using [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html) openCV documentation, but getting this error

`No viable overloaded '='`

on

`boundRect[i] = cv::boundingRect( contours_poly[i] )`

```
cv::Mat mat;
UIImageToMat(image, mat);

cv::Mat gray;
printf("number of channels = %d",mat.channels());
cv::cvtColor(mat, gray, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);

cv::Mat bin;

cv::threshold(gray, bin, 0, 1, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
std::vector<std::vector<Point> > contours;
std::vector<std::vector<Point> > hierarchy;
cv::findContours(bin, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

std::vector<std::vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
std::vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );



for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    cv::approxPolyDP( contours[i], contours_poly[i], 3, true );
    boundRect[i] = cv::boundingRect( contours_poly[i] );//Getting Error here


}
```

Comment: Share code snippet instead of sharing image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `cv::boundingRect()` returns `cv::Rect` value. Change

`std::vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );`

to

`std::vector<cv::Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );`